# selector jquery of input into td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello i have a td of class **TdbeforeForcage** and into it i added an input with a value to make td value editable so i have a problem that all td value have the same number but each input should take the value of td.

Here my HTML :

```html
<tr class="forc" style="font-size : @fontSize; font-weight: @fontWeight;">
   <td style="font-size:14px;text-align:left;">@ech.Key.Titre</td>
   @foreach (var x in ech.Value)
   {
   if (x == "<BR>")
   {
   <td style="font-size:14px;text-align:right">-</td>
   }
   else if (x == "-")
   {
   <td style="font-size:14px;text-align:right">@x</td>
   }
   else if (counter == counterTotal)
   {
   <td style="font-size:14px;text-align:right">@x</td>
   }
   else if (x.Contains("/"))
   {
   <td style="font-size:14px;text-align:left">@x</td>
   }
   else if (counter != counterTotal && x != "-" && isforcagerevision)
   {
   <td class="forcage" style="font-size:14px;text-align:right;">
   </td>
   }
   else
   {
   <td class="TdbeforeForcage" style="font-size:14px;text-align:right">@x</td>
   }
   counter++;
   }
</tr>
```

Here my js i think i have a problem in the selector :

```js
$("tr.forc td.TdbeforeForcage").each(function () {
var html = $(this).html();
var input = $('<input class="numberforce" style="width:50%" type="text" />');
input.val(html);
$(this).html(input);
if (html.indexOf('&nbsp;') > -1)
{
var newValue = html.replace('&nbsp;', '');
$("tr.forc td.TdbeforeForcage input.numberforce").val(newValue);
}
});
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to accomplish. Is it to dynamically add an input to td.TdbeforeForcage? And what value should the input take of td?

Comment: I didnt get what are you trying to do. But this error "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" means that JQuery is missing or some conflict is happen. Can you check if the JQuery is correctly defined in your application?

Comment: @dteterevkov look i have added pictures to explain more the problem after adding the jquery code i have all td editable with an input but the value is not correct all input take the value of last td but each input should take the value of the td

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem may be in line

`$("tr.forc td.TdbeforeForcage input.numberforce").val(newValue);`

You are getting `newValue` but then setting it to all inputs of class numberforce, to fix it, you should reference the `td` self and then change the newly added input, as so:

`$(this).find('input.numberforce').val(newValue)`

Comment: Thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

$("tr.forc td.TdbeforeForcage").each(function() {
            var html = $(this).html();
            var input = `$('<input class="numberforce" style="width:50%" type="text" />');`
            input.val(html);
            $(this).html(input);
            $(this).find('input.numberforce').val($.trim(html));
        });